# Crontab on Solaris 10

Tags: service, cron, solaris-10, sparc

I was trying to execute the following:

```
root@sol10 # /lib/svc/method/svc-cron
root@sol10 # /usr/sbin/cron: GenMacKey: not found
```

I would like to know how to generate GenMacKey.

Better still my `crontab -r` is returning,

```
root@sol10 # crontab -r
cron may not be running - call your system administrator
```

Answer (score 4):

Well for the second problem, cron may be disabled.  You can use  the command:

```
svcadm enable cron
```

to reenable it.

To restart cron you can use:

```
 svcadm restart cron
```